# Very slow MySQL code (inline and JOINS)

Tags: mysql, join, inline

How can I restructure the query below to run faster? It takes several minutes to run, which slows down the webserver significantly. The query gets details of a product from several tables, using inline queries and joins. I have a feeling there must be a faster way.

What is the most efficient way of writing the query below?

```
SELECT p.*, 
   pd.*, pd.NAME AS NAME, pi.*,p.image AS default_image, 
   (SELECT first FROM  product_shipping psi 
    WHERE  psi.product_id = p.product_id)         AS flat_rate, 
   (SELECT NAME FROM   manufacturer m 
    WHERE  m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id) AS manufacturer, 
   (SELECT price FROM   product_special ps 
    WHERE  ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = 8) AS special_price 
   FROM   product p 
      LEFT JOIN product_description pd 
          ON ( p.product_id = pd.product_id ) 
      LEFT JOIN product_image pi 
          ON ( p.product_id = pi.product_id ) 
    ORDER  BY p.product_id
```

Comment: i recommend to use JOIN's instead of subquery

Comment: Can you show DB structure?

Comment: thanks for this - is it possible to restructure this so that it completely uses joins?

Comment: You are using `first` and `price` fields in your sub-query. However, it was never used in your outer query. So, what's the point of invoking them in your sub-query?

Comment: @Edper a subquery that returns only one column in an inline select is already returning that column value. So `first` will become flat_rate and so on

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Thanks I did not perceive it right away. Thanks for the correction once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good bit of the items in your select are duplicated, but since that's how you were getting the data originally, I've kept it as is.  Also, using `LEFT JOIN`s can be slower than `INNER JOIN`s:

```
SELECT 
    product.*,
    product_description.*,
    product_description.NAME AS NAME,
    product_image.*,
    product.image AS default_image,
    product_shipping.first AS flat_rate,
    manufacturer.NAME AS manufacturer,
    product_special.price AS special_price
FROM
    product
        LEFT JOIN product_description ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id
        LEFT JOIN product_image ON product_image.product_id = product_image.product_id
        LEFT JOIN manufacturer ON product.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id
        LEFT JOIN product_special ON product.product_id = product_special.product_id AND product_special.customer_group_id = 8
ORDER BY product.product_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You need indexes, if you do not have them.  The following come to mind:

- `product_shipping(product_id, first)`
- `manufacturer(manufacturer_id, name)`
- `product_special(product_id, customer_group_id, price)`
- `product_description(product_id)`
- `product_image(product_id)`
- `product(product_id, manufacturer_id)`

Re-arranging the subqueries and joins will probably have little effect on the performance, if you don't have the right indexes in place.

Comment: Thanks for this. Some of the indexes didn't exist, so this should definitely help

Answer (score 1):

Different from the answer given by @Harper I chose to do inner joins since you are doing it on the inline selects, so my suggestion will be:

```
 SELECT p.*, 
        pd.*, pd.NAME AS NAME, pi.*,p.image AS default_image, 
        psi.first AS flat_rate, 
        m.NAME AS manufacturer, 
        ps.price AS special_price 
   FROM product p 
       INNER JOIN product_shipping psi 
           ON (psi.product_id = p.product_id)
       INNER JOIN manufacturer m
           ON (m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id)
       INNER JOIN product_special ps
           ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = 8)
       LEFT JOIN product_description pd 
           ON ( p.product_id = pd.product_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN product_image pi 
           ON ( p.product_id = pi.product_id ) 
 ORDER  BY p.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this is really helpful. I wasn't totally sure how to convert the inline mysql to inner joins

Comment: Glad that it helped. But you be aware of two things here. 1 - Consider the answer given by @GordonLinoff it would improve your query performance; 2 - This approach may not bring all rows from your original query because an inline select may not have equivalente rows for the subquery, therefore it will result in a null value for that column a LEFT JOIN as in the answer given by Harper Maddox will return exactly as the inline selects if there is no equivalent it will result in null for that column.

Comment: I added this answer as a reference on how to convert inline to pure joins :)